# TypeScript: overload won't match primitive types

Tags: typescript

I can't get this overload to work:

```js
// Overload signatures
export function isStringValidDate(str: undefined): false;
export function isStringValidDate(str: string): boolean;

// Implementation signature
export function isStringValidDate(str?: string): boolean {
    if (typeof str === 'string') {
        return !isNaN(Date.parse(str));
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'd like to ensure that the only time that a `true` value is returned is when a `string` is supplied to the function. Whenever I try to call `isStringValidDate` with an optional string, I get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(str: undefined): false', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(str: string): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.
```

Comment: ① What's an "optional string"?  Can you show the call you're having a problem with so that this is a [mre]? ② If you want to allow calling with `string | undefined`, your second call signature should be `(str?: string) => boolean` instead of `(str: string) => boolean`, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3oXAm) shows. ③ Unless you plan for someone to literally call `isStringValidDate(undefined)` in their TS code, there doesn't seem to be a benefit to having multiple call signatures; what, specifically, goes wrong if you just do as [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wXyjkN) shows?